# ClassNotFoundException when running clojure jar

Tags: clojure, netbeans-6.9, enclojure

I am trying to run a clojure jar file and I get the error below:

```
C:\Users\Nahashon>java -jar C:\Users\Nahashon\.m2\repository\org\enclojure\sample\0.0.1\sample-0.0.1.jar
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mode/mdzw

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mode.mdzw
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
Could not find the main class: com.mode.mdzw. Program will exit.
```

The clojure project is created using maven on netbeans 6.9.1. and the clojure code is as below:

```
(ns com.mode.mdzw
(:gen-class))

(defn -main []
(println "Looks like it works!"))
```

The POM file is as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<properties>
    <clojure.version>1.1.0</clojure.version>
</properties>
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>org.enclojure</groupId>
<artifactId>sample</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1</version>
<name>mdzw</name>
<description>mdzw</description>
<build>
 <sourceDirectory>src/main/clojure</sourceDirectory>
 <testSourceDirectory>src/test/clojure</testSourceDirectory>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/clojure</directory>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <testResources>
        <testResource>
            <directory>src/test/clojure</directory>
        </testResource>
    </testResources>
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>com.theoryinpractise</groupId>
    <artifactId>clojure-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <sourceDirectories>
            <sourceDirectory>src/main/clojure</sourceDirectory>
        </sourceDirectories>
        <clojureOptions>-Xmx1G</clojureOptions>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>compile-clojure</id>
        <phase>compile</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>compile</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
      <source>1.5</source>
      <target>1.5</target>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>

  <!-- -->
   <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <archive>
                <manifest>
                    <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                    <mainClass>classes.com.mode.mdzw</mainClass>
                    <classpathPrefix>dependency</classpathPrefix>
                </manifest>
            </archive>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>

</plugins>
</build>
<repositories>
  <repository>
  <id>central</id>
  <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
  </repository>
<repository>
  <id>clojure-releases</id>
  <url>http://build.clojure.org/releases</url>
</repository>
<repository>
  <id>incanter</id>
  <url>http://repo.incanter.org</url>
</repository>
<repository>
  <id>clojure-snapshots</id>
  <url>http://build.clojure.org/snapshots</url>
</repository>
<repository>
  <id>clojars</id>
  <url>http://clojars.org/repo/</url>
</repository>
</repositories>
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.clojure</groupId>
   <artifactId>clojure</artifactId>
   <version>${clojure.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.clojure</groupId>
   <artifactId>clojure-contrib</artifactId>
   <version>${clojure.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>swank-clojure</groupId>
   <artifactId>swank-clojure</artifactId>
   <version>1.1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <exclusions>
      <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.clojure</groupId>
        <artifactId>clojure</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
      <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.clojure</groupId>
        <artifactId>clojure-contrib</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
   </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

What am I not doing right?

Comment: It seems that AOT compilation was not done .. check your jar file and see if the com/mode/mdzw path structure is there or not and there should be a class file called mdzw.class

Comment: You are right Ankur, there is no mdzw.class file. How can I achieve this?

Comment: You need to set `:aot :all` in your clojure project.clj file then do `lein jar` and then use this newly created jar

Comment: Thanks Ankur, It seems lein is better than maven.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using [leiningen](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen) if you're just getting started, at which point you can try [Ankur's advice above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13008429/classnotfoundexception-when-running-clojure-jar#comment17683817_13008429) or set a `:main` in project.clj.

```
(defproject org.enclojure/sample "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.4.0"]]
  :main com.mode.mdzw)
```

Then just run `lein run` to launch your program. If you want a jar you can execute w/o lein, build it with `lein uberjar`.

See the [leiningen tutorial](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/preview/doc/TUTORIAL.md) for more.

If you want to stick with maven (which I haven't used much), you should probably look at the documentation for the [clojure-maven-plugin](https://github.com/talios/clojure-maven-plugin), which is already in your pom, but maybe not set up right. It provides a `clojure:compile` goal that probably does what you need.

I suppose the obvious question is, what goal(s) are you running before running `java -jar C:\Users\Nahashon\.m2\repository\org\enclojure\sample\0.0.1\sample-0.0.1.jar`?

Comment: Thank you Duelin. I think I will try out lein. It seems it's better than maven for clojure going by the recommendations I have seen on many blogs I visited.

Comment: leiningen is simpler, but lots of Clojure projects, including Clojure itself and (I believe) all the contrib projects you see here https://github.com/clojure and here http://build.clojure.org/ use Maven, so you're in good company if you want to stick with Maven.

Comment: McKibet, if this was useful you could vote it up and/or mark it as the answer.